# Add to spring cloud gateway routes incrementally

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to make a list of routes, which are just holders for the route's ip, port and path.

```
public class Route {
    String ip;
    String port;
    String uri;
//constructor
//getters and setters
}
```

then, placing my routes in a list and iterating over them to add them to the gateway routes.

```
 @Bean
    public RouteLocator myRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        for (Route route : routes) {
            log.info("route is: " + route.toString());
            builder.routes().route(r -> r.path(route.getUri()).uri(route.getIp() +  route.getPort());
        }
        return builder.routes().build();
}
```

but it's not working, my guess is it resets the routes with the return statement or even with each route added, but I don't know how to go around that.

Comment: The additional `routes()` call is what resets it. Call routes once and keep a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @spencergibb 's comment, calling routes() reset the routes, which got solved by referencing builder.routes()